# android studio - AnimatedVectorDrawable's behave weirdly

Tags: android, radio-button, animatedvectordrawable

I'm trying to insert green ticks on the right side of radio buttons whenever the user checks one of them, but drawables are behaving weirdly.

Initial state(none is checked):
[image]

then I check the first one, having recovered this one as isVisible=true and the other one isVisible=false:
[image]

seems ok. Then I check the second one, having recovered this one as isVisible=true and the other one isVisible=false:

[image]

A new animation starts on the previous rb and I don't understand why.
Then I try to tick the first one again:

[image]

A new animation starts at a scrambled position. Then I tick the second one again:
[image]

So my attempts were done either inside the radio group set as horizontal, adding two imageViews , or by creating a new LinearLayout which I overlapped to the radio group so that the ticks were in the right position according to the RB's.

Programmatically, I tried both either creating two AnimatedVectorDrawable objects for each RB or one shared between the two, with no success.

```
private lateinit var rb1: RadioButton
    private lateinit var rb2: RadioButton
    private lateinit var rb_1_checked: ImageView
    private lateinit var rb_2_checked: ImageView
    private var rb1_done: AnimatedVectorDrawable? = null
    private var rb2_done: AnimatedVectorDrawable? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.mylayout)
        rb1 = findViewById(R.id.rb_1_id)
        rb2 = findViewById(R.id.rb_2_id)
        rb_1_checked = findViewById(R.id.IV_1_id)
        rb_2_checked = findViewById(R.id.IV_2_id)
        rb1_done =
            AppCompatResources.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.avd_done) as AnimatedVectorDrawable
        rb2_done =
            AppCompatResources.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.avd_done) as AnimatedVectorDrawable
        rb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
            rb_1_checked.isVisible = true
            rb_2_checked.isVisible = false
            rb_1_checked.setImageDrawable(rb1_done)
            rb1_done!!.start()
        }
        rb2.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
            rb_1_checked.isVisible = false
            rb_2_checked.isVisible = true
            rb_2_checked.setImageDrawable(rb2_done)
            rb2_done!!.start()
        }
    }
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it by changing setOnCheckedChangeListener to setOnClickListener, and also changed isVisible with isInvisible to keep position of the ticks